# Where did the word "yourn" originate?

Tags: etymology

"Yourn" as in yours. Where did it originate? I think from the southern US, but not sure.

Comment: Short for 'your one'. *Your'ne* is present in some UK dialects, particularly, I think, in the Midlands.

Comment: I'd always assumed it's a contracted form of [*your **one***](http://www.alphadictionary.com/bb/viewtopic.php?t=3691), as per that link. It might be common today in some American regional dialects, but it's not American in *origin*. OED says it's modelled on *mine, thine*, and they have it recorded since 1382, so it long predates America.

Answer (score 7):

*Yourn*, *ourn*, *hisn*, *hern*, *theirn* all originate in the Anglo-Saxon Mid Anglian dialectal grammar (Cambs, Hunts, Beds) and contain the pronoun weak ending still present in *mine* and *thine*.  My family originated in Cambs and evidently retained its dialect speech even when the Industrial Revolution obliged them to move to London in the 1830s.  My grandfather said *yourn*, etc and my father said it (and I do!) whereas my grandmother's family and my mother's family came from different parts of Suffolk (East Anglian dialect) where they didn't say it.

They are not contractions of *your one* or *your own* at all.  The Samuel Pegge quotation is correct - the ancient grammar lingered longer in Mid Anglia than elsewhere which is why it has survived.  The Americans and Australians inherited it through colonization.

Answer (score 3):

John Bartlett, [*Dictionary of Americanisms*](http://www.merrycoz.org/voices/bartlett/AMER14.HTM) (1848) offers the following entry for *yourn*:

> **YOURN.** This is a contraction of *your own*, or a change in the termination of the pronoun *yours*, in conformity with *mine*, and which is much used by the illiterate and the vulgar. It is also used in in London, and in the West of England. "The cockney," says Mr. Pegge, "considers such words as *our own* and *your own* as pronouns possessive a little too much expanded ; and therefore thinks it proper to curtail them, and to compress them into the words *ourn* and *yourn*, for common daily use." —*Anecdotes of the English Lang[uage]* [1814], p. 193.
>
> He might have added *hisn*, as in the famous distich:
>
> > Him as prigs vot isn't *hisn*
> >
> > Ven he's cotch'd 'll go to pris'n.

Samuel Pegge himself says, in [*Anecdotes of the English Language*](http://books.google.com/books?id=OnASAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA198&dq=%22ourn+and+yourn%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=-HA1VP3oF5bioASX8IAI&ved=0CCEQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22ourn%20and%20yourn%22&f=false), second edition (1814):

> *Ourn* and *yourn* are also actual Saxon Pronouns Possessive ; for the Saxon *ure* (our) in the Nominative Case has for its Accusative *urne* ; and the Saxon Pronoun *eower* (your) gives the Accusative *eowerne* ; and nothing is necessary to warrant the use of them, but a mutation of Case. Whether *urne* be a Dissyllable, and *eowerne* a Trisyllable, matters not ; because, by removing the final *e* (a letter of no weight in that situation), these Saxon words must ultimately terminate in the letter *n*, a circumstance which would soon be brought about by raid pronunciation.

Comment: Interesting that they say it’s from _your own_. I’ve always mentally associated it with _your_ ***one***.

Answer (score 3):

Living in Nottingham in the 1940's and 1950's we habitually used yourn, theirn and ourn as possessives. We also said yoursen, mesen hissen for yourself, myself and himself. Despite this, my pompous grammar school English teacher insisted there was no Nottingham  dialect, only laziness!
Personally I feel proud at playing a part in preserving those anglo saxon forms in the unwritten common speech through hundreds of years. Sadly they now seem to be dying out thanks to the constant exposure to Mid-atlantic English via the media.

Answer (score 2):

OED says it's modelled on *mine*, so I believe it comes from the following analogy:

> *my* is to *mine* as *your* is to *yourn*

The more common word *yours* comes from the following constructions:

> *her* is to *hers* as *your* is to *yours*.
>
> *our* is to *ours* as *your* is to *yours*.

Comment: That seems like a good analogy. Why did 'my' go to 'mine' but other pronouns go other ways?

Comment: @Chaim _My_ didn’t “go to” _mine_; it’s the other way around. The original form was _mine_ (well, _mīn_ in Old English), but just like what happened with _an_, the final /n/ was lost before consonant sounds. Later on, in _mine_ and _thine_, it was also lost before vowels, just like it’s been lost in _an_ in some modern dialects of English as well.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet And sometimes the "n" jumps from one word to another. There are some words that now begin with a vowel, but originally began with "n". "a n<word>" was misheard as "an <word>" and the latter stuck; sometimes the opposite happened. https://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2014/11/13/metanalysis/

Comment: @Barmar Yes, rebracketing is a common enough occurrence, but it’s not really related to the reduction of complex syllables in unstressed function words. Rebracketing is also, in other circumstances, responsible for things like _helipad_ and _workaholic_, which are quite different.